# Using member functions in operator overloading definition (error with const)

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, operator-keyword

I am getting error in the operator overloading definition. The error goes away if I remove the consts in the parameters. Is there any way I can get it working without removing the consts in the parameters? Also what is happening behind them?

```
class Vector3D{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    float dot(Vector3D& v) {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }
}; 
inline float operator *(const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b) {
    return a.dot(b);
}
```

Comment: You simply need to define the member function `dot` const

Comment: The problem is that your member function needs to be const. Better would be just to make it a non-member function since it can use the public interface to calculate the dot product. See Scott Meyers' algorithm for when to make something a member function in "[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)".

Comment: @cdhowie It actually needs to be `float dot(const Vector3D &v) const {`

Comment: Indeed, missed the argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should qualify the member function `dot` as `const` as well, otherwise you can't call this member function on a `const` object:

```
float dot(Vector3D const& v) const {  // <-- const here
```

You also need to accept `v` by `const&` since you are passing it a `const` object.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the error, but it says something like : "cannot call non-const method on const object". Your `dot` does not modify members and should be declared as `const` also the argument is not modifed, hence should be `const`:

```
class Vector3D{
public:
    float x, y, z;
                                // v---------------- allow to call on const objects
    float dot(const Vector3D& v) const {
            //  ^----------------------------------  pass parameters as const ref
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }
}; 
inline float operator *(const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b) {
    return a.dot(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Vector3D::dot` function, neither the object for member function call nor the argument object are modified.

To tell this to the compiler, you should add two `const`s to your `dot` definition.

```
class Vector3D{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    float dot(const /*(1)*/ Vector3D& v) const /*(2)*/ {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }
}; 
inline float operator *(const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b) {
    return a.dot(b);
}
```

(1) : telling that the argument object is not modified
(2) : telling that the object for member function call is not modified